# How to receive a null character in gets function from the user input in c program?

Tags: c

I have the program in c

```
int main() {
    char str[1];
    gets(str);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to give the input `'\0'` to cause the `str[0]` to represent the null character but it's actually store the character `\`.

Is there an input that will cause that?.
Thanks.

Comment: To begin with, never ***ever*** use `gets`. It's a [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) function, that have even been removed from the C specification. Secondly, that's not how input work. You could try to press `Ctrl-A` (followed by `Enter`) and hope for the best.

Comment: Also, what is the *real* problem you want to solve by giving the null-terminator as input? Why do you need to do that?

Comment: You could try `echo -n "" | myprog`, or you could use Control-D to terminate the input if you're at the beginning of a line. An input of any length other than zero will cause undefined behaviour, because `str` is only large enough to hold an empty string. If you want to catch null bytes in the input, perhaps you could use `getchar()` instead.

Comment: On which operating system are you running your program?

Comment: What do you mean with `give the input '\0'`? Did you enter these four characters? In that case you would expect that your program interprets the entered text and converts it to the ASCII-null character. But there's no code for it. `gets` only reads a string into a buffer. That buffer is too small in your example program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  `Ctrl-A` is usually `'\1'`, not `'\0'`.  Some keyboards allow `Ctrl-@` for  `'\0'`.

Comment: @harper   "gets only reads a string into a buffer" -->   In detail, `gets()` does not read a null character terminated _string_, but a `'\n'` terminated _line_ - which it then saves as a _string_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to receive a null character in gets function from the user input?

The obsolete, since c11, function `gets()` reads a *line* of text and then saves it (without the `'\n'`) with an appended *null character* insuring a *string*.

**gets()**

> The gets function reads characters from the input stream pointed to by stdin, into the array pointed to by s, until end-of-file is encountered or a new-line character is read. Any new-line character is discarded, and a null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.  C99 §7.19.7.7 2

**line**

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into *lines*, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined.  C99dr §7.19.2 2

**string**

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character. C99dr §§7.1.1 1

---

> Is there an input that will cause that?

Yes.  Entering a *null character* on various keyboards is not easy.  Sometimes a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl @</kbd>) will work.  Some keyboards lack or obscure any way to input a *null character*. Usually a re-directed input from a file that contains a *null character* into `stdin` will suffice.

Entering <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> is not entering a *null character*.

---

An important consideration is that with `gets()` or `fgets()`, the input of a *null character* is not special in its reception.  A following <kbd>Enter</kbd> (`'\n'`) or end-of-file-signal is still needed.  After which a  *null character* is appended.

With `gets()`, the size of the input buffer needs to be **at least 2** to read in any input more than an empty line of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so `char str[1];` is too small to save an input of a null character with the appended null character.

If the input was <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `gets(str)` would save no input in `str[0]` and then append a *null character*  to `str[0]`.

If the input was <kbd>Ctrl @</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `gets(str)` would save the user inputted *null character* to  `str[0]` and then append a *null character*  to `str[1]`.

---

Let  us try an example with `fgets()`.

```
int main(void) {
  // Form a file of 1 byte
  FILE *f = fopen("zero.txt", "w");
  if (f == NULL) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  fputc('\0', f);
  fclose(f);

  f = fopen("zero.txt", "r");
  if (f == NULL) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  char buf[80];
  memset(buf, 42, sizeof buf);
  fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", buf[i]);
  }
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0  // from the file zero.txt
0  // the appended null character
42
42
42
```

---

Text processing functions like `fgets()`, `scanfs()`, `fscanfs()` and the obsolete `gets()` having to cope with a user inputed *null character* is a corner case.  Such input is either a mistake or, more likely, a hacker attempt to break the program.

Answer (score 1):

A  <kbd>NUL</kbd> character cannot be *inside* a C string, since by definition it is ending a C string.

(The <kbd>NUL</kbd> character is `'\0'` -practically, a zero byte- and is of course different of the  `NULL` *pointer*).

And your `str` is probably too small. Consider declaring it with `char str[32];` and clearing it with `memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));` before reading into it.

So what your user would input is not a string, but simply a sequence of bytes (you might read character by character a stream of bytes using [getchar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar)). Hence you cannot use [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) for reading (of course, forget about `gets`, it is obsolete, dangerous, and removed from the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard. Read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) to check).

A different question is what should your user do to enter such a <kbd>NUL</kbd> character on the keyboard. Such details are operating system specific (on some systems there might be no way to type a <kbd>NUL</kbd> character, on other systems you might have to press several keys simultaneously, including the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key). You could consider some [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) from some binary file containing <kbd>NUL</kbd> bytes.

It is surprising (and very unusual) that you want to enter a <kbd>NUL</kbd>; I am guessing that you are mis-undestanding your homework.

Perhaps you want to handle the empty input case. For that, you need to explicitly detect the end-of-file condition (e.g. when `getchar` gives `EOF`, which is *not* a character). Beware that [feof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) is only valid after some (failed) read operation.

Be sure to compile with all warnings and debug info (with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: you're right there is no reason for a user to press NUL, I wanted the memory to hold the number 0 (which 0 is the null character ascii) which letter I could convert the 4 chars to integer (and get 0 in that integer)

Answer (score 0):

when we declare char str[1],we give instruction to compiler that str is string having 1 byte,'\' is also one charactor.
string defination also states that char array ending with '\0' is called string.

As per your declaration we can give only one char which '\'.